# django 1.3 class based views -> FormView, initial carried over between requests?

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

I'm running into a stange issue in Django and I think it might be because I don't properly understand how class based views work.

Basically I have a ListView and a FormView. one is to list the objects, the other is to edit.

In a browser, if i navigate from listview to the formview of an existing object I get the expected result: the form fields are filled in with expected values.

The same formview is used for presenting a blank form where a user can create objects.
If i navigate from the form of an existing object to the formview of a new object or to the listview and then to the formview of a new object, initial (i.e. self.initial of the CBV) is prepopulated with information from the existing object previously visited.
Obviously I'm expecting self.initial to be blank at the beginning of a new get request.

My understanding was that each request generates a new instance of a classbased view. How is initial getting carried over across requests?
I'm coming to this conclusion based on some debugging. relevant lines in get_initial() below.

```
def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
    initial = super(M_EditNewsletterView, self).get_initial(**kwargs)       
    fs_logger.debug('initial immediately after super -> %s' % initial)
```

SO suggested this was similar, but I don't understand the answer with the upvote.
[Django(trunk) and class based generic views: one form's initial data appearing in another one's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019070/djangotrunk-and-class-based-generic-views-one-forms-initial-data-appearing-i)

can anyone help explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

`get_initial` will simply return the value based on the `initial` property for the class. Just a guess - but are you setting `initial` like this?

I.e.

```
class M_EditNewsletterView(FormView):
    #this value will essentially be constant as it belongs to the 
    #class, not the instance
    initial = get_my_value()
```

You should override the 'get_initial' method yourself.

```
def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
    return get_my_value()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Unfortunately no. I am overriding get_initial.... the current hack to fix the problem is in fact to set the first line in get_initial() as initial = {}